# Ajax en ruby on rails , no funciona el proceso remote: true

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un formulario en el home ( todo creado con scaffold) ,el cual quiero que al dar en el botón  publicar me agregar por medio de ajax  la publicación al mismo home.

agregue remote true al formulario

```
= form_for @post, remote: true do |f|
```

efectivamente en el inspector de elementos  del navegador, en el formulario me aparece el:

```
data-remote="true"
```

La cosa es que aun cuando envió la petición en js  siempre me redirecciona  a `http://localhost:3000/posts/28`

en vez de quedarse en la misma pagina esperando el archivo de respuesta para poderlo agregar a la pagina home

estoy utilzando rails 5.0.3
¿sabe alguien si para esa version de rails (remote: true ya no funciona) o toca hacer otro paso para poder detener la respuesta en html?

Comment: ¿Tienes `jquery` y `jquery_ujs` en el `application.js`?

Comment: Te recomiendo que visites esta url: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html, ve al punto 4 ahi se muestra el ejemplo que quieres

Comment: si , aparecen como //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debo agradecer a [Martouta](https://github.com/Martouta) quien hizo un [fork](https://github.com/arturobr123/Rails/pull/1/commits/5dfb92b8a2456404d491a36f411f64cb393ea6b1) al respecto.

sucedía que en app/controllers/posts_controller.rb faltaba una linea especificando  `format.js { render :show }` para que la respuesta en js fuera aceptada.